# Object is not Iterable in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

It's my first contact with react.js. I don't know it! Please, do not hate me for some stupid questions!

I try to create global context, due to this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tnt2y7D3V9o but it doesn't work. Browser shows error "TypeError: Object is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))"

My App :

```
//my imports here

import {MyContext} from "./contexts/AppContext";
import React, { useState, useContext } from 'react';

function App() {
    const [state, setState] = useContext(MyContext); **// web browser indicates here!**

    return (
        <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">

      </nav>
          <nav className="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
              <div className="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNav">
                  <ul className="navbar-nav">
                      <li className="nav-item">
                          <a className="nav-link" href="/">Home <span className="sr-only"></span></a>
                      </li>
                      <li className="nav-item">
                          <a className="nav-link" href="/products">Produkty <span className="sr-only"></span></a>
                      </li>
                      {!state.isLogged &&
                      <li className="nav-item">
                          <a className="nav-link" href="/register">Rejestruj sie <span className="sr-only"></span></a>
                      </li>
                      }
                      {!state.isLogged &&
                      <li className="nav-item">
                          <a className="nav-link" href="/login">Loguj sie <span className="sr-only"></span></a>
                      </li>
                      }
                      {state.isLogged &&
                      <Logout />
                      }

                  </ul>
              </div>
          </nav>

        <Route path="/" component={Welcome}/>
        <Route path="/products" component={Products}/>
        <Route path="/register" component={Register}/>
        <Route path="/login" component={Login}/>

  </div>
        </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

And my AppContext file:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Cookies from 'js-cookie';


const startState = {
    email:'',
    isLogged: false,

};


export const MyContext = React.createContext();

const AppStore = ({ children }) => {
    const [state, setState] = useState(startState);

    useEffect(() => {
        const email = localStorage.getItem('email');
        const logged = Cookies.get("authenticator");

        const checkSession = Cookies.get();
        console.log(checkSession)
        console.log(logged)
        if (logged) {//if  logged
            setState({ email: email, isLogged: true })
        }
        else {
            setState({ email: email, isLogged: false })
        }

        console.log(email);
    }, []) // <-- empty dependency array

    return (
        <MyContext.Provider value={[state, setState]}>{children}</MyContext.Provider>
    );
}


export default AppStore;
```

Could someone indicate on a bug? I have no idea where it could be. I console.logged context in App.js - and it's not empty! I don't know what "is not iterable".
Once again - please don't hate me, and don't give me thumb down.
Thank you in advance!

EDIT: I've added arguments to context constructor. Now it's

```
export const MyContext = React.createContext([[],() => {}]);
```

But it's not solve my error!

Comment: Which line of code is throwing the error?

Comment: I added pointer in comment in the``` code. const [state, setState] = useContext(MyContext); **// web browser indicates here!**``` BTW: I solved my problem ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Problem solved!
First of all I need to add arguments to context constructor:

```
export const MyContext = React.createContext([[],() => {}]);
```

Second - I involuntary used `<Router>` insted `<RouterBrowser>` in App.js file.

This tutorial showed bad way for creating Context (be aware!)

Thank you all!